# Why does the terminal set have exactly one element?

Tags: category-theory

I'm reading Lawvere/Rosebrugh's *Sets for Mathematics*.

He states the axiom of the terminal set:

> **AXIOM:** TERMINAL SET
>
> There is a set $1$ such that for any set $A$ there is exactly one mapping $A \to 1$. This unique mapping is given the same name $A$ as the set that is its domain.

And then he gives this definition:

> **Deﬁnition 1.3:** An element of a set $A$ is any mapping whose codomain is $A$ and
> whose domain is $1$ (or abbreviated... $1 \stackrel{\alpha }{\longrightarrow}  A$).

And then asks:

> Why does $1$ itself have exactly one element according to this deﬁnition?

I answered the following:

> Taking the axiom of the terminal set, which states that there is a unique mapping  $A \to 1$ and taking the definition of mapping (for each $x\in A$ there is an $x\in B$), then every element of $A$ is connected to one element of $1$, and the only way to achieve a unique mapping in this respect is to have exactly one element in $A$.

Is it correct?

Comment: It seems a bit roundabout. Considering the definition of $1$ with $A=1$, we find that there is exactly one mapping $\alpha : 1 \to 1$. So we're done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. You shouldn’t be thinking in terms of the familiar notion of mapping at all. Just apply the axiom to the set $A=1$: there is a unique mapping $1\to 1$. Each element $\alpha$ of $1$ is a mapping $1\overset{\alpha}\longrightarrow 1$, and there is only one such mapping, so $1$ has a unique element.

Comment: Oh, thanks. But what's the problem of using the familiar notion of mapping?

Comment: @Vÿska: Although I’ve not seen the book, it appears from what’s in your question and the fact that Lawvere is one of the authors that it’s a category theoretical approach, and if so, you very likely don’t have the familiar notion at this point: I’m guessing that the mappings are at this point just abstract entities associated with pairs of sets.

Answer (score 3):

To have two different elements in the set 1, you need two different mappings from 1 to the set 1 - that's the definition of an element.  But there is a unique mapping from 1 to 1 by the terminal set axiom.